# How to apply a two-color gradient to a cell background using xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, excel, gradient, xlsxwriter

I have a minimal working example using `xlsxwriter` to apply a **solid** background color to a cell in Excel:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook  = xlsxwriter.Workbook("hello_world.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
# Is there a way to make a format for a 2-color gradient?
bgformat = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': "#abcdef"})
worksheet.write('A1', "Hello world", bgformat)
workbook.close()
```

But I want to apply a **2-color gradient** to a cell using `xlsxwriter`. Excel itself provides this functionality via "Format Cells" (see screenshot below).

[image: screenshot]

I don't see anything in the `xlsxwriter` docs for applying gradient colors to cells (I see this functionality for charts, but not cells). Does anyone know if this is possible via `xlsxwriter`?

**Edit:**
I've tried to add a gradient format using these commands, but they each throw an error and I'm just making random guesses based on the syntax for making a chart with gradient colors.

```
# bgformat = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': "#abcdef"})
# bgformat = workbook.add_format({'gradient': {'colors': ['red', 'green']}})
# bgformat = workbook.add_format("bg_color": {"gradient": {"colors": ['red', 'green']}})
# bgformat = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': ['red', 'green']})
# bgformat = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': {'colors': ['red', 'green']}})
# bgformat = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': {['red', 'green']}})
bgformat = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': {"gradient": ['red', 'green']}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradient cell colors aren't currently supported in XlsxWriter.

Comment: Well, I guess that settles that. Thank you!

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks. XlsxWriter is a wonderful resource.